New Windows Server 2022 RemoteApp deployment disconnects UDP clients after 1 minute idle
I migrated a Windows Server 2012 R2 running Terminal Services (RemoteApp) to Windows Server 2022.
Everything is identical. On the old server, we had no problem with RDP UDP being enabled. On the new 2022 server, when RDP UDP is enabled, the RemoteApp session is closed after one minute of idle/ inactivity, and I can't figure out why.
Same networks, same VPN, same client PCs, same applications, same firewalls, same web filtering. I've tried disabling all of above and nothing fixes the issue. As soon as I disable UDP connections the issue is fixed.
The error we get is:
Your network configuration doesn't allow the necessary HTTPS ports.....
Error Code 0x300004a

There is something on Windows Server 2022 with some sort of UDP timeout, and it's not the firewall. Any suggestions?

At a minimum you need to collect network packet captures on both ends so they can be correlated. Also if this occurs in one minute that isn't a "timeout". Not a normal intelligent timeout anyway. I believe the lowest value that is allowed for keep alive is one minute.

I cant tell why UDP want to switch to https, but 0x300004a direct to a certificate error, does the server certificate is on the computer store to thrust it ?

I believe that this may a trust rather than a thrust issue ;) , but mostly does the app open or does it close because of idling?

So this is a timeout. If you keep clicking in the RemoteApp, you can keep it open indefintately, it's only if you leave it idle that the remote desktop connection closes. The app stays open in it's session, so when you reconnect, the app is there there, as you left it. The certificates are in the trusted root, otherwise the RemoteApp wouldn't work at all.
It's definitely not a timeout in the RemoteApp collection in the Remote Desktop settings. It's some sort of UDP-only timeout on the 2022 server. Could be in IIS, but I don't know where to look there.

You can take a look at the following log on the client device and see if you can find something useful: Event viewer -> Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> TerminalServices-ClientActiveXCore
